# C++: Class C does not name a type (new scenario) 3 classes

Tags: c++

first apologies if this is a repeated question, but I did research on this and also search a lot of existing threads, but haven't seen an answer. could you guys please put your thoughts on below?

```
//A.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
class B;
class A
{
    B * b;
};
#endif A_H

//B.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include "A.h"
class B
{
    A *a;
};
#endif B_H    

//testerA.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include "A.h"
class testerA
{
    A *a;       // GETTING ERROR A DOES NOT NAME A TYPE
};
#endif A_H
```

Now, I was wondering even if the forward declaration of class B is causing the issue,
but if I remove the forward declaration of B from A.h and any other references, I still get the issues, I am wondering am I doing some silly mistakes which other eyes might be able to catch?

EDITS:

## ifndef are already declared.

The class A and B when compiled without the testerA work fine. but something's wrong with testerA.

Comment: First, you need include guards or you'll get yourself in a sticky wicket eventually. Add `#pragma once` at the top of each `.h` file. (This is technically non-standard but virtually every compiler supports it. Alternately, do the usual `#ifdef`ery.) What is the very first error message you are getting? Always start at the top and track that one down.

Comment: You forgot to put semicolon after the class definitions. Other than that, could not reproduce the problem: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jy1fBm5Ib6JDxi0H Create a [mcve].

Comment: @metal - i do have the #ifdef include guards, would #pragma help?
eerorika - Sorry those are plain typos, i have semicolons in my original code.

Comment: the first error is "A DOES NOT NAME A TYPE"

Comment: If you have the `#ifndef` include guards, then include them in the code you provide. Otherwise everyone who comes across this question is going to get hung up on that. The code you provide should be code that you have written on your machine and attempted to compile to verify that it duplicates the error. That code should then be copy-pasted here exactly as it appears on your machine. You shouldn't be typing any code here from memory. That's how typos and miscommunication creep in.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this.

Comment: Edited the original question to add the #ifndef guards.

Comment: What is the very first error your compiler reports? (If you are using Visual Studio, do not look at the "Error List" for this purpose because it sometimes reorders things and hides relevant details.) Follow that trail, and you will find your problem. Alternately, use wandbox linked above to re-create your actual problem using actual code in multiple files. It could be that you're picking up another file called `A.h` on your machine. Try putting a `#error` in `A.h` to force an error and make sure that file is being included as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys, specially @metal, i am actually using dummy code above to replicate the issue I am facing, the issue was that the header guards that I used in testerA.h were same as that of A.h which caused A.h to not include testerA.h, thankfully this was a silly mistake and not a design problem :D

Comment: One of the benefits of the quasi-standard `#pragma once` is that you can't make that error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your include guards in `testerA` are wrong, replace them with:

```
#ifndef TESTER_A_H
#define TESTER_A_H
...
#endif
```

`#ifndef` tells the compiler to only read everything until the `#endif`, if the variable (in your case `A_H`) is **not** defined.

When your compiler copies `testerA.h` it defines `A_H`, so when it gets to read `A.h`, it does not read the content of the file at all. The result, is that the compiler does not find any definition for class `testerA`